# If $\text{Im}(S^*M)\subseteq \text{Im}(M)$, is $\text{Im}(SM)\subseteq \text{Im}(M)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $F$ be a complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators defined on $F$.

> Assume that
>
> - $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$ (i.e. $\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$).
> - $S\in\mathcal{B}(F)$ such that $\text{Im}(S^*M)\subseteq \text{Im}(M)$.
>
> It is true that
> $$\text{Im}(SM)\subseteq \text{Im}(M)\;?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: $F = \mathbb C^2$,
$M= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $S= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.